# connecting google_container_node_pool with google_compute_backend_service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing

i want to connect this to services (google_compute_backend_service and google_container_node_pool)

So i added  google_compute_instance_group because the backend_service can't handle other instance services apart from instance_group and tried to add to it the node_pool instances.

```
# Créer un pool de nœuds GKE
resource "google_container_node_pool" "pool" {
  name       = "pool-juice-shop"
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.mon_cluster.name
  location   = google_container_cluster.mon_cluster.location

  node_count = 1
  node_config {
    machine_type = "n1-standard-2"
    # Autres configurations du nœud
  }
}

resource "google_compute_instance_group" "my_instance_group" {
  name        = "my-instance-group"
  zone        = "us-central1-a"
  description = "My instance group description"

  instances = google_container_node_pool.pool.instances
}

resource "google_compute_backend_service" "redacted-service-backend" {
  name        = "backend"
  port_name   = "redacted"
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  timeout_sec = 3

  backend {
    group = google_compute_instance_group.my_instance_group.self_link
  }
}
```

this is the error :

Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on cdr.tf line 45, in resource "google_compute_instance_group" "my_instance_group":
│   45:   instances = google_container_node_pool.pool.instances
│
│ This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named "instances".

Comment: The documentation says that the `instances` argument is in the `self_link` format, if that helps.

Comment: Can you explain your end goal?  Behind the scenes, a GKE node pool is a MIG, but you would not generally use it as a backend until you have something deployed.  And to create LB or ALB services, you would generally use an Ingress or Service of type Load Balancer.